# Limit of contour integral is zero

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-analysis, analysis, contour-integration

Let $S_n$ be the square of vertex $(n+1/2)(\pm 1 \pm i)$ in $\mathbb{C}$ and let
$$ f(z) = \frac{1}{z\tan(\pi z)}.$$
For $z\in\mathbb{C}$ such that $z$ is not a pole of $f$, I want to show that
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{\partial S_n} \frac{f(w)}{w-z}\, dw. $$
I know that the poles of $f$ are the integers with multiplicity $1$ except $0$ with multiplicity $2$. I tried to use the ML inequality but the length of $\partial S_n$ tends to infinity and I don't arrive to compute an estimation of $\sup_{\partial S_n}|f|$.

Comment: What do you want to show the integral to be equal to? Are you aware of the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem and can you calculate the residues of $f$?

Comment: The necessary bounds on $\cot$ on this contour are proved in the textbooks, e.g. at 19.13 in Priestley's Complex Analysis which is available online.

Answer (score 0):

To show that the limit of the integral is 0 as n approaches infinity, we can use the residue theorem. The integral over the square can be split into four line integrals, and by the residue theorem, the sum of these line integrals is equal to 2πi times the sum of the residues of the function inside the square. Since the square is centered at z and the size of the square goes to 0 as n goes to infinity, the distance between z and the poles of the function inside the square also goes to 0. Therefore, the sum of the residues of the function inside the square approaches 0 as n goes to infinity, and so the limit of the integral is 2πi times the sum of the residues which is 0

To apply the residue theorem, we can break down the integral over the square into four line integrals:

**1.** Integral over the top side of the square, from $\left ( n+\frac{1}{2} \right )+(1+i)$ to $\left ( n+\frac{1}{2} \right )+(1-i)$

**2.** Integral over the right side of the square, from $\left ( n+\frac{1}{2} \right )+(1-i)$ to $\left ( n+\frac{1}{2} \right )-(1-i)$

**3.** Integral over the right side of the square, from $\left ( n+\frac{1}{2} \right )-(1-i)$ to $\left ( n+\frac{1}{2} \right )-(1+i)$

**4.** Integral over the right side of the square, from $\left ( n+\frac{1}{2} \right )-(1+i)$ to $\left ( n+\frac{1}{2} \right )+(1+i)$

To compute these line integrals, we can parameterize the complex numbers on each side of the square with t:

**1.** Top side: $w(t)=\left ( n+\frac{1}{2} \right )+(1+i)t, \; t\in [0,1]$

**2.** Right side: $w(t)=\left ( n+\frac{1}{2} \right )+(1-i)+2it, \; t\in [0,1]$

**3.** Bottom side: $w(t)=\left ( n+\frac{1}{2} \right )-(1-i)t, \; t\in [0,1]$

**4.** Left side: $w(t)=\left ( n+\frac{1}{2} \right )-(1+i)-2it, \; t\in [0,1]$

Then we can compute each integral as:

**1.** Integral over the top side:
$$\int\limits_{\partial S_n}^{\mathrm{top}} \frac{f(w)}{w-z} dw = \int\limits _0^1 \frac{f((n + 1/2) + (1 + i)t)}{((n + 1/2) + (1 + i)t) - z} (1 + i) dt$$
**2.** Integral over the top side:
$$\int\limits_{\partial S_n}^{\mathrm{right}} \frac{f(w)}{w-z} dw = \int \limits_0^1 \frac{f((n + 1/2) + (1 - i) + 2it)}{((n + 1/2) + (1 - i) + 2it) - z} (2i) dt$$
**3.** Integral over the top side:
$$\int\limits_{\partial S_n}^{\mathrm{bottom}} \frac{f(w)}{w-z} dw = \int\limits_0^1 \frac{f((n + 1/2) - (1 - i)t)}{((n + 1/2) - (1 - i)t) - z} (-1 - i) dt$$
**4.** Integral over the top side:
$$\int\limits_{\partial S_n}^{\mathrm{left}} \frac{f(w)}{w-z} dw = \int\limits_0^1 \frac{f((n + 1/2) - (1 + i) - 2it)}{((n + 1/2) - (1 + i) - 2it) - z} (-2i) dt$$

To find the sum of the four integrals, we can add them together:

$$\int\limits_{\partial S_n} \frac{f(w)}{w-z} dw = \int\limits_{\partial S_n}^{\mathrm{top}} \frac{f(w)}{w-z} dw + \int\limits_{\partial S_n}^{\mathrm{right}} \frac{f(w)}{w-z} dw + \int\limits_{\partial S_n}^{\mathrm{bottom}} \frac{f(w)}{w-z} dw + \int\limits_{\partial S_n}^{\mathrm{left}} \frac{f(w)}{w-z} dw$$

The four integrals are over the top, right, bottom and left sides of the square, respectively. The sum of the integrals is

$$\int\limits_0^1 \frac{f((n + 1/2) + (1 + i)t)}{((n + 1/2) + (1 + i)t) - z} (1 + i) dt + \int\limits_0^1 \frac{f((n + 1/2) + (1 - i) + 2it)}{((n + 1/2) + (1 - i) + 2it) - z} (2i) dt + \int\limits_0^1 \frac{f((n + 1/2) - (1 - i)t)}{((n + 1/2) - (1 - i)t) - z} (-1 - i) dt + \int\limits_0^1 \frac{f((n + 1/2) - (1 + i) - 2it)}{((n + 1/2) - (1 + i) - 2it) - z} (-2i) dt$$

The integral is over a closed path, so the sum of the four integrals should be equal to zero.

Since the poles of the function inside the square all approach z as n goes to infinity, and the sum of the residues is zero, the limit of the integral as n goes to infinity is also zero. The sum of these four line integrals is equal to $2\pi i$ times the sum of the

Comment: Why should the sum of the four integrals be zero? Your first paragraph seems to be nonsense, too. This is quite dependent on the particular function and the very particular contour.